# I can't add a custom private packages from git with yarn 3 but I can add with yarn 1.22.18

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarn-v2, yarn-v3

I create a custom private repo as library from git. I want to use that library into another project but and I try to add that library with this syntax:
yarn add "@git+"
but I use yarn 3 and its bring the project external libraries without building. When I set yarn version to 1 I works fine.

At the end of day I want to use yarn 3 in my project so how can I solve this?

[the error is in pic when I use yarn 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsbZP.png)

[My both project use react (v18) and typescript]

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the problem: yarn-3 pnpm has a bug about for that problem and they fix it in 21 which is https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/855 . So in my packaage.js file I changed `prepare` script to `prepack` it helps.